How to convert a glb 3D design file to a step file in python?
I have found several libraries, pythonOCC, pygltflib which have data exchange functions. However, I cannot figure out how to convert a GLB file to a STEP file.
For example, pythonOCC has a read_gltf_file and write_step_file function.
I use pygltflib to read a GLB and save as GLTF (just a json version of GLB). However, I pythonOCC fails to read and convert this to STEP.
GLB --(pygltflib)--> GLTF --(pythonOCC)--> STEP

Do any tried and tested libraries exist for this conversion?
Here is what I do:
from OCC.Extend.DataExchange import read_gltf_file, write_step_file
from pygltflib import GLTF2

geom = GLTF2().load(glb_src_file)
geom.save_json(gltf_file) # I can open this file in Windows 3D Viewer

gltf=read_gltf_file(glt_file, verbose=True) # [] empty list for some reason

if gltf:
    write_step_file(gltf) # only if the last step works.

what I want is a function:

def glb2step(path):
    # what to do here?
    # writes step file to disk

The sample glb file I am working with is here.

stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file(stl_file_path)
shell = TopoDS_Shell()
builder = BRep_Builder()
builder.MakeShell(shell)

for i in range(len(stl_mesh.vectors)):
    triangle = stl_mesh.vectors[i]
    polygon = BRepBuilderAPI_MakePolygon()

    for j in range(3):
        point = gp_Pnt(float(triangle[j][0]), float(triangle[j][1]), float(triangle[j][2]))
        polygon.Add(point)
        polygon.Close()

        face = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(polygon.Wire()).Face()
        #fix_wires(face)
        #face = fix_face(face)
        builder.Add(shell, face)

        sewing = BRepBuilderAPI_Sewing()
        sewing.Add(shell)
        sewing.Perform()
        sewn_shell = sewing.SewedShape()

        topods_builder = TopoDS_Builder()
        compound = TopoDS_Compound()    
        builder.MakeCompound(compound)
        topods_builder.Add(compound, sewn_shell)

        # Create a STEP writer
        step_writer = STEPControl_Writer()
        step_writer.Transfer(compound, STEPControl_AsIs)
        # Write to a file
        status = step_writer.Write(output_path)
        print('finished')

